# Require all files from directory

Tags: node.js

Help me please.

I want require all files from directory ?
How best to do it?

I read about require_paths but it does not perform those functions.

Comment: @GurpreetSingh nodejs require is not the same as requirejs

Comment: I try seach!Thanks WiredPrairie

Answer (score 0):

You can walk through a directory and require each one:

```
var mods = {};
var files = fs.readdirSync('your_directory').filter(function(x) { return x.substr(-3) == ".js"; });
for(var i = 0; i != files.length;++i) {
    mods[files[i]] = require(path.join('your_directory',files[i]));
}
```

Comment: @MichelPhelps You do know how to include it in node right.